# Smb.conf parameters

Tags: smb

I have a question about permissions on smb.conf file, because i have two users, and i need to set up like usr1 can read and write on /files directory, and also i need that usr2 can only read the /files directory, I have something like this but it' doesnt work, i have the two users in the same group...

```
#[files]
#path = /files
#writable = yes
#browsable = yes
#guest ok = yes
#guest only = yes
#create mode = 0777
#directory mode = 0777

#[files]
#path = /files
#public = no
#writable = no
#browsable = yes
#guest ok = no
#valid users = usr2, @users
#create mask = 0765
```

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's because everything is commented out.  Remove the '#' from each line.  If I were doing it I would only have one share defined in my smb.conf file

```
[files]
path = /files
writable = yes
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = usr1, usr2, @users
```

Then use normal Unix permissions (or acl's) on the files themselves to grant/deny access.

Comment: Yes i commented to post here, but i have uncommented on my file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by now, I put it to everyone but only user1 can write.

[Files]
comment = shared-directory
path = /files
public = no
writable = no
browsable = yes
create mask = 0777
create mode = 0777
directory mode = 0777
write list = @user1